# Laravel Pint formatting issue with line breaks in comments

Tags: php, laravel, phpcs, php-cs-fixer, laravel-pint

I'm using Laravel Pint for code styling in my Laravel project. I have a function with a multi-line comment block that includes various tags such as @description, @author, and @email. When I run Laravel Pint to format my code, the comment block gets formatted,
Here's an example of the original comment block:

```
/**
 * @description THis is a function
 * @author Arafaht
 * @email arafath@gmail.com
 */
```

```
/**
 * @description THis is a function
 * 
 * @author Arafaht
 *
 * @email arafath@gmail.com
 */
```

As you can see, there are new lines added after the parameters. I need to avoid this formatting.
I've checked PHP_CS Fixer docs, but I couldn't find any specific rules or settings related to this. Is there a way to configure Laravel Pint to avoid this? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling phpdoc_separation  worked for me:

[PHPCSFIXER](https://cs.symfony.com/doc/rules/phpdoc/phpdoc_separation.html)

"phpdoc_separation": false